# Operators with infinite number of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When dimension of a space is more than 1, then identity operator and zero operator has infinite number of invariant subspaces.

I wonder, if there are other operators that have infinite number of invariant subspaces?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&1&0\cr0&0&17\cr}$$

Comment: Using block matrix - that's clever! I haven't thought about that.